# Not all CSS properties will be able to cascade down or some tags will ignore properties from parents?

Tags: html, css

**My HTML**

```
<div class="teaser">
<img src="smiley.gif">
</div>
```

In my CSS, I am trying to apply a border-radius: 100% to the image so it looks like a circle. When I do

`.teaser{ border-radius: 100%; }` it won't work but `.teaser img{ border-radius: 100%; }` it will.
What are the reasons? Is it because **border-radius** property can't be cascade down or is it because the **img** tag will ignore properties from the parents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties That Inherit by Default

```
border-collapse
border-spacing
caption-side
color
cursor
direction
empty-cells
font-family
font-size
font-weight
font-style
font-variant
font
letter-spacing
list-style-type
list-style-position
list-style-image
list-style
line-height
orphans
page-break-inside
quotes
text-align
text-indent
text-transform
visibility
white-space
widows
word-spacing
```

source : [impressivewebs.com/](http://www.impressivewebs.com/inherit-value-css/)

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, for `border-radius`, you should use `overflow:hidden` to crop your content.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/FSK75/

Answer (score 2):

[`border-radius` is not inherited](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius)

Here's a list of CSS properties so you can check whether it is inherited or not: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Properties

Comment: Just be careful, 'cause that list is not exhaustive -- for example, it doesn't include `border-radius` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

CSS

```
.teaser {
   border-radius: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   display: table-caption;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="teaser">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-189-137-4.jpg">
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSK75/2/)